# How use "ScrollArea" in python PYQT

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I'm from another country and I'm just learning english then get it

All today's morning I had tried to make the code work
I do not know what to do 
My purpose is Scroll GroupBox which keep many-many buttons

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'buttons.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.10.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(378, 368)
        buttons = []
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 80, 141, 151))
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        for i in range(1,30):
            buttons.append((QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox), QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)))
            buttons[-1][0].setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, i*30, 90, 25))
            buttons[-1][0].setObjectName("group_{0}".format(i))
            buttons[-1][1].setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, i*30, 20, 25))
            buttons[-1][0].setObjectName("del_{0}".format(i))
        # Two next rows can be comment to show the groupBox
        scroll = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        scroll.setWidget(self.groupBox)


        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Имя группы"))

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Please, help me. I do not know what to do!

Answer (score 1):

It won't work mostly for these reasons:

- `scroll` is a local variable, so Python will garbage collect it as soon as `setupUi` returns;
- it has no parent set, so it wouldn't be shown;

Also, most importantly, you should **NEVER** edit the output of pyuic for any reason (even if you believe you know what you're doing, but if you knew, you wouldn't edit it). Follow the guide about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) to understand the correct way of dealing with those files (which must only used as imported modules).

Since you're trying to create your interface by code, there's no use in having a "Ui object", just do it in the main window class.
I also suggest you to always try to avoid fixed geometries, but use layout managers instead.

```
class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # if the scroll area is the only "main" widget of the window, use it
        # as the central widget
        scroll = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(scroll)

        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox()
        scroll.setWidget(self.groupBox)
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)

        # create a grid layout for the groupbox
        groupLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox)

        # the above is the same as:
        # groupLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        # self.groupBox.setLayout(groupLayout)


        for row in range(30):
            button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
            button1.setFixedWidth(90)
            groupLayout.addWidget(button1, row, 0)
            button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
            button2.setFixedWidth(20)
            groupLayout.addWidget(button2, row, 1)
```